# Python Tkinter размещение объектов сверху в центре

Tags: python, tkinter

Как мне расположить объекты в Python Tkinter так,  чтобы строка кнопок была сверху в центре, казалось бы, такая простая задача, но ни `.pack()`, ни `.grid()` не хотят работать так как надо. В документации нет такого, неужели тут провал на ровном месте?

[image: Примерное расположение объектов]

пример кода:

```
    ttk.Button(text='Сайт').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
    ttk.Button(text='Инфо').grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
    ttk.Button(text='Форум').grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N)
    ttk.Button(text='ВК').grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=N)
```

К сожалению, параметр `sticky` работает не совсем так, как хотелось бы, а `.pack()` не подходит для этого, так как нет возможности выстроить в линию объекты ровно по центру сверху

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Я изменил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача действительно не сложная. Создать *Frame*, разместить его вверху. И потом в него уже добавить кнопки. Можно *grid*'ом, можно *pack*'ом.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

app = tk.Tk()

frm = tk.Frame(app)
frm.pack()

ttk.Button(frm, text='Сайт').pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=3)
ttk.Button(frm, text='Инфо').pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=3)
ttk.Button(frm, text='Форум').pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=3)
ttk.Button(frm, text='ВК').pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=3)

app.mainloop()
```

[image: -]